# Is it possible to extend an Xunit "Collection" instead of having to use an IClassFixture?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, xunit

I've been converting some existing tests to use Collection. I currently have a case though where I want to do something like this:

```
[Collection("MyCollection")]
public class SomeTests
{
    public SomeTests(SomeFixture someFixture)
    {
        // Initialize something once
        var foo = InitializeFoo();
    }
}
```

SomeFixture takes a long time to initialize, which is why I moved it to a collection. I have many test classes using SomeFixture but only like 2 classes need Foo. I'd like to initialize Foo only once (per test class is fine) but would like to avoid adding Foo into SomeFixture if possible.

Is there some way to extend the Collection just for this test class so that I can initialize Foo only once and then use that same Foo in every test within SomeTests?